# Error modifying LB Listener Rule: ValidationError: Up to '2' conditions may be specified status code: 400, request id

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I want to set multiple paths with aws_alb_listener_rule resource
but aws_alb_listener_rule resource should not be able to accept multiple values in the condition object?

Below is my resource. however, the error written in the title is out,
how can i fix that

```
resource "aws_alb_listener_rule" "admin_static" {
  listener_arn = "${aws_alb_listener.web_http.arn}"
  priority     = 99

  action {
     type             = "forward"
     target_group_arn = "${aws_alb_target_group.ec2_web.arn}"
 }

 condition {
    field  = "host-header"
    values = ["example.com"]
 }

 condition {
    field  = "path-pattern"
    values = ["/admin/*"]
 }

 condition {
   field  = "path-pattern"
   values = ["/static/*"]
 }

}
```

Answer (score -3):

I added the new source code and solved that Error modifying LB Listener Rule: ValidationError

Comment: What you mean by new source code, same issue here for me, can u pls help ?

Comment: can you put more details regarding how have you exactly resolved the issue, giving your actual resolution according to the example in question? the answer, as it is now, is useless.